# Realizar animación al realizar scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, animated

Quiero realizar una animación en un sitio web con jquery cuando se realice scroll:

```
$('.skillbar').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
        width: $(this).attr('data-percent')
    }, 1500);
});
```

Son unas barras de de porcentajes y quiero que cuando se realice *`scroll`* en la pagina se haga la animación, no se di al *`scroll`* se le puede colocar una cantidad de `px` para que se realice cuando llegue a un determinado punto.

Comment: Utilizando css y con el :target podemos [crear animaciones](https://codepen.io/AlberPedraza/pen/ygDBq)

Answer (score 2):

Si estás utilizando jQuery, pon un *escucha* en el evento:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(evt) { ... });
```

Es decir:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {

    // Hacer el 'espacio'
    var $div = $("#text-div");
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      $div.append($("<p/>").text(i));
    }

    // Escuchar el evento scroll
    $(window).on("scroll", function(evt) {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scrollTop > 1000) {
        // animar
        console.log(scrollTop);
      }
    });

  });
</script>
<div id="text-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No hay una forma nativa en CSS para hacer esto, la única opción es escuchar el evento scroll y hacerlo a mano.

Otra cosa que debes saber es como calcular donde estas y las dimensiones de la ventana para poder calcular la posicion del elemento a animar:

1. `$(window).scrollTop()` te el numero de linea de la primer linea visible. Es decir, que si hay 600 pixels ocultos (scrolleados para arriba) retorna 601.
2. `$(window).innerWidth()` y `$(window).innerHeight()` retornar las dimensiones ancho y alto del area visible de la ventana. Estas son importantes para saber cuando el elemento animado sale y entra en escena.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo adaptado a jQuery (por la etiqueta).

1. Escuchar el evento scroll.
2. Calcular la posición del elemento en base a `$(window).scrollTop()`
3. Actualizar la posición del elemento a animar

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
  var left = ($(window).innerWidth() - 100) * $(window).scrollTop() / 3000;
  $('#bola').css('left', left);       
});
```

```css
#escenario {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
}

#bola {
   position: fixed;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
   border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="escenario">
<div id="bola"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo de forma nativa o con jQuery deberías hacer uso de los eventos onscroll() o $.scroll(), respectivamente; irías recuperando y calculando la posición del viewport.

Podrías intentar con una librería que te puede simplificar esta labor como lo es [Scroll Magic](http://scrollmagic.io), te aportaría bastante a lo que queres lograr.